# How can I make IE recognize HTML 5 tags?

Tags: internet-explorer, html

What are some good solutions for making my HTML 5 pages compatible with IE (at least IE 7 & 8)?

Is there an industry standard that I can use that will make IE recognize things like `<article>` and `<nav>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can run the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) if you want, which is what you seem to be referring to. It'll allow IE to parse the tags initially. But that will still leave you with the same problems if you want to use `innerHTML` (or framework code based on it). There's the [innershiv](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/), but it's not wonderfully efficient and it won't work for all top-level elements.

What do you want to achieve by using the semantic-but-behaviour-free elements like `<article>`? You will be taking on extra browser problems for little practical benefit. To be honest, I really wouldn't bother, today. It's something for the future.

Comment: I've been reading through diveintohtml5.org and liked the idea of what they were talking about as far as the semantic elements went. With IE 9 coming out and with almost all of the other browsers supporting the html 5 tags, I was curious if there was a standard way people handled IE 7/8.

I'm writing HTML on a large website that will be in place for possibly years to come. I'd like it to be as "future" proof as possible while still remaining backwards compatible with older browsers.

Comment: I would do `<div class="article">` for now, reserving the HTML5 element names as class names for this purpose. Then it's a fairly easy automatable change in the future. (Similar to how we do `<input class="text">` now, to work around IE6's lack of support for the CSS attribute selector, whilst making it clear what it means.)

Comment: Don't forget to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in your head to get IE9+ compatibility without having to use 'the shiv'.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: Just use `document.createElement('whatever')`

http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/