# CSS - display property not working as expected with IE

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `display` rules that i can't get to work
I can't use the `display` property with IE version < 10, i'm using this code:

```
Comments(<fb:comments-count href="http://mypage"/></fb:comments-count>)
```

That results in:

```
Comments(<fb:comments-count href="http://mypage" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class=" fb_comments_count_zero">
    <span class="fb_comments_count">
        10
    </span>
</fb:comments-count>)
```

With this css:

```
.fb_comments_count {
    display: inline;
}

.fb_comments_count_zero {
    display: inline;
}
```

It displays:

```
Comments(
10
)
```

instead of

```
Comments(10)
```

I tried also changing

```
display:inline
```

to

```
display:inline-block
```

But it's not working.

The other issue i'm having is when i use `display:none`. In fact, IE<10 doesn't hide what i'm styling, but IE10, chrome, opera and firefox don't have that problem.

How can i fix this?

P.S. I prefer **not to use JavaScript**, because i want my site to look good even if javascript is disabled.

Comment: I guess it's because `<fb:>` is not a supported tag. I suppose it's a Facebook tag?

Comment: @poepje You are right, it's a facebook tag for including comments into the site, but i'm not styling the tag, i'm styling the tag's class, that should be supported by all browsers

Comment: Clearly the `<fb:comments-count>` is being styled with `display:block`. This would be the default for an unknown element (particularly in older IE versions which don't play well with unknown elements). What doctype are you using (if you're using an xhtml doctype, it will be picking up the `<fb:comments-count>` element as an embedded XML element with a namespace; this may give you different layout defaults to an HTML doctype. Either way, my preferred solution would be to drop it from the rendered HTML output unless you really need it to be there.

Comment: I guess so yeah, after all there are plenty of sites which use this and (I assume) work in IE as well. But Spudley's suggestion seems a good one, if you're not already using html5, try it (the doctype is simply `<!doctype html>`)

Answer (score 0):

You're using dashes instead of underscores in your CSS.

```
.fb-comments-count {
    display: inline;
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
.fb_comments_count {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This is not the problem, it was just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer will not style any element it is not aware of. That is why there is a HTML5 shim javascript; to inform IE of the new HTML5 elements (insert them into the DOM). Other browsers won't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure how FBML gets rendered in the end, but older IEs don't recognize custom tags and won't apply css to them, so this might be the issue. You need to ["register" the tags to the IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15977113/1047823).

Also you should avoid the linebreaks in your span:

```
<span class="fb_comments_count">10</span>
```

this already might fix your first problem, if not try to apply `white-space:nowrap;`.

Comment: I tried but i can't get it work... I tried adding either `fb` and `fb-comments` to the tags list in this (separated with `|`) but the `display` rules over the `fb:comments` element are still being ignored

Answer (score 0):

ie has always had a problem with braking lines where it should not try adding this to your css

> white-space:nowrap;

If that does not work then please tell me what happens.
I have had these problems before with ie so it not just you.
also try wrapping your fb tag in a p tag then add a style of choice to the p tag.